# jQuery / Attach a div element inside another element and target/control the parent one

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

for a mobile version of a website i’m using jQuery to create a div element (close button) inside another div (checkbox elements):

```
  var $newDiv = $("<div/>") 
                .addClass("closebtn")  
                .html("Close [X]");
  $(".checkbox_elements").prepend($newDiv);
```

This works fine but when I add a click function to the div inside (close button), I can’t "hide" the parent div (checkbox elements):

```
  $(".closebtn").click(function(){
    $(".checkbox_elements").css("display", "none");
   //or
    $(this).prev(".checkbox_elements").css("display", "none");       
  });
```

When I attach the close button to any other element outside the checkbox elements div it works fine.
How can I get the click function to work inside the checkbox elements div container?

Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the button(`closebtn`) is added dynamically, you need to try [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$('.checkbox_elements').on('click', ".closebtn", function () {
    $(".checkbox_elements").css("display", "none");
    //or
    $(this).parent(".checkbox_elements").css("display", "none");
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Arun. When I use this event delegation, the checkbox_elements div "flashes" like being selected but it still stayes visible.

Comment: @user3277479 can you help recreating the issue http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3HQSt/1/

Comment: Thanks for your support!!! My setting looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/3HQSt/6/ Mobile environment can hardly be rebuilt. I guess the css :hover state contradicts the jquery css state when the close button is placed inside the parent element? Your former solution works fine in a "clean" environment.